# JAX-RS RESTful API working with JSON representations and linking resources

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, resteasy

Sometimes it's confusing how I should link resources within a RESTful API, consider for example the entities:

Profile (Users can create business profiles with address, details, etc..)

Plan (Already persisted in app's DB, created by administrators)

The request to create a Profile looks like:

```
POST /profiles
{
  "name": "Business name",
  "address": "The address",
  "phone": "0000000000" 
}
```

Now it is required that a Profile belongs to a Pricing Plan. So is it a good idea to do POST request like this with JSON?

```
POST /profiles
{
  "name": "Business name",
  "address": "The address",
  "phone": "0000000000"
  "plan": {
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

and then load the plan by the provided *id* and associate it with the profile being created:

```
@POST
@Path("/profiles")
public Response createProfile(Profile profile) {

    // load plan resource from DB
    Plan plan = em.find(Plan.class, profile.getPlan().getId())

    // associate
    profile.setPlan(plan);

    // persist profile
    em.perist(profile);
}
```

The Profile entity:

```
@Entity
public class Profile implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "plan_id", nullable = false)
    private Plan plan;

    private String name
    ...

    // getters and setters

}
```

The Plan entity:

```
@Entity
public class Plan implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "text")
    private String description;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 8, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal price;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer days;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="plan", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Profile> profiles;

    ...

}
```

In other words i am asking what I should pass to the request body in order to link a reference entity.

I would like to believe that something like this is more reasonable:

```
POST /plans/1/profiles
```

but according to the REST and JSON semantics what would be the best option?

I can also think of other ways such as providing the Plan id as a query param:

```
POST /profiles?planId=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you need to do the following:

Create profile with

```
POST: /profile
```

Assign plan with

```
PUT: /profile/<profile_id>
{
   "name": <optional>,
   "plan_id": <optional>,
   ...
}
```

First thing is you separate create and update (POST/PUT). Another is you state profile ID for update in URL.

You can set parameters you need to update in PUT request body and update only parameters which are set. Think it's fine with REST concept.

Comment: `PUT` has the semantics of replacing the whole content with the body payload found within the request! If you want to update partial data only, consider `PATCH`, though patch is also [a bit more complicated](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/). Splitting `POST` and `PUT` though (if `POST` only creates the resource without content) adds an idempotent semantic to the resource creation, which it otherwise would not have.

Comment: @RomanVottner, was patch accepted as a part of HTTP in a standard? I can't find it in spec on w3c.

Comment: My fault, found it. Then it may make sense to use LINK method (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2068#section-19.6.1.2) since it defines relationship between resources.

Comment: The problem with `PATCH` though is, that it is [not yet widely supported](https://blogs.oracle.com/theaquarium/entry/using_http_patch_with_jax). Also, instead of plain `application/json` mime-type, a more RESTful document type like [`application/hal+json`](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) is more appropriate

Comment: @Stan my intention is not to update the Profile entity after its been created and add a "pricing Plan" but imagine of the plans already persisted in the db and when someone is trying to create a new Profile he must specify the Plan as it is required. My question is what is usually done with situations like that? is passing the plan id in the JSON payload an acceptable approach? And if not what else can be done?

Comment: @MichalisDaniilakis, i would say it's completely acceptable to pass plan id on creation. We used approach like this before and everyone was agree it's fine.